# Apple IOS8 Action Extension template is not working with Photo

Tags: swift, ios8

I was trying to get the Action Extension template that is automatically created when adding an Action Extension to a project. By default it is suppose to accept an image and display it. But when trying to use it in Photo, the picture is a jpeg and imageView.image = image as? UIImage is not setting the image. imageView.image is nil.

```
var imageFound = false
for item: AnyObject in self.extensionContext!.inputItems {
    let inputItem = item as NSExtensionItem
    for provider: AnyObject in inputItem.attachments! {
        let itemProvider = provider as NSItemProvider
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as NSString) {
            // This is an image. We'll load it, then place it in our image view.
            weak var weakImageView = self.imageView
            itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as NSString, options: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error) in
                if image != nil {
                    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                        if let imageView = weakImageView {
                            imageView.image = image as? UIImage
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

            imageFound = true
            break
        }
    }

    if (imageFound) {
        // We only handle one image, so stop looking for more.
        break
    }
}
```

But the Objective C equivalent works just fine

```
BOOL imageFound = NO;
for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
    for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {
        if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
            // This is an image. We'll load it, then place it in our image view.
            __weak UIImageView *imageView = self.imageView;
            [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
                if(image) {
                    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                        [imageView setImage:image];
                    }];
                }
            }];

            imageFound = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (imageFound) {
        // We only handle one image, so stop looking for more.
        break;
    }
}
```

Has anyone been able to get the template working?

You can get this code by going to "File/New/Target" & Choose Application Extension/Action Extension" from a Swift project in Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to cast UIImage in swift iOS 8 Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887242/unable-to-cast-uiimage-in-swift-ios-8-extension)

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for now that might be useful for other people finding this same problem:

I have created a objective c utility class that calls "loadItemForTypeIdentifier" from objective c and returns the image. I call this function from Swift and works just fine.

```
@protocol UtilitiesDelegate
- (void) setImage:(UIImage*) image;
@end

@implementation Utilities
+ (void) loadItemForImage:(NSItemProvider *)itemProvider delegate:(id<UtilitiesDelegate>)utilDelegate
{
    [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage options:nil completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
        if(image)
        {
            [utilDelegate setImage:image];
        }

    }];

}
```

and you can call

```
Utilities.loadItemForImage(itemProvider, delegate: self)
```

instead of

```
itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as NSString, options: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error) in
        if image != nil {
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
                if let imageView = weakImageView {
                    imageView.image = image as? UIImage
                }
            }
        }
```

I know it is not a proper fix, but it works.

Comment: Did you ever discover a Swift fix for this? I'm having the same issue.